# NaN error while retrieving element from json data

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I am beginer in javascript

I have following data:

```
data[i] = '{"Name":"'+car[i]+'","Price":"'+retail[i]+'"}';
```

I want to use value of retail[i] as y position of svg('.dot')

```
 svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return 10; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Price); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return 'Red'; });
```

but i am getting

```
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"
```

I have also tried .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(Number(d.Price)); })
What mistake i am doing?

Comment: try return y(parseInt(d.Price, 10))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data[i] variable is a string as far as it is shown in your question. To fix this, either make that variable an object (the better solution) or use JSON.parse to parse that string and convert it to an object

I'd construct object for data[i] like so

```
data[i] = {"Name":car[i],"Price":retail[i]};
```

Answer (score 0):

may be the data is in string format, did you try
`.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(Number(JSON.parse(d).Price)); })`

Answer (score 0):

It shows , you are passing NaN value (Not a Number). So you have to pass the value as integer value..

Use parseInt() to convert to integer..